# GCM messages are not received unless SEND permission is removed

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

In order to implement GCM correctly, a `com.google.android.c2dm.SEND` permission should be specified for the receiver as per [the official docs](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html):

> The receiver should require the com.google.android.c2dm.SEND permission, so that only the GCM Framework can send a message to it.

When I add that permission however, I get this error when a message is received.

> W/GTalkService(25224): [DataMsgMgr] broadcast intent callback: result=CANCELLED forIntent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE cat=[com.XXX.XXX] (has extras) }

followed by this error:

> W/ActivityManager(283): Permission Denial: broadcasting Intent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE cat=[com.XXX.XXX] flg=0x10 (has extras) } from com.google.android.syncadapters.contacts requires com.google.android.c2dm.SEND due to receiver com.XXX.XXX/com.XXX.XXX.GcmBroadcastReceiver

If I remove that permission only, without changing anything else, the receiver works normally and I can process the message.

and here's the receiver definition in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<receiver
        android:name="com.XXX.XXXX.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />

            <category android:name="com.XXX.XXX" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

I'm using the debug certificate during testing, in case that might be relevant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND` instead of `com.google.android.c2dm.SEND`, such as:

```
<receiver
  android:name="GCMBroadcastReceiverCompat"
  android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE"/>
    <category android:name="com.commonsware.android.gcm.client"/>
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

(from [this sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Push/GCMClient2))

Comment: Thanks. That fixed it. The sample manifest in the official docs actually has it correctly. The preceding text explanation uses the incorrect com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND though.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

<receiver
        android:name="com.robustastudio.mateegy.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>

            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />

            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

            <category android:name="com.robustastudio.mateegy" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```